# Combine large numeric vectors into a dataframe via loop (R)

Tags: r, vector, merge, reduce

I am trying to learn what is the appropriate way to combine ~50 numeric vectors (each vector has ~20k items) into a dataframe via a loop.

These vectors have the same names in a same order, but different values. They look like:

```
#Vector 1
v1 = c(1, 20, 3, 2, 50)
names(v1) = c(geneA, geneB, geneC, geneD, geneE)

#Vector 2
v2 = c(25, 12, 43, 0, 50)
names(v2) = c(geneA, geneB, geneC, geneD, geneE)

#... total 50 vectors like these
```

I would like to have a final table after a loop looks like (feel free to change the row names):

```
          geneA   geneB   geneC   geneD   geneE
values_v1   1      20       3       2      50
values_v2   25     12       43      0      50
...
values_v50...
```

Of note, the numeric vectors are outputs from a particular library so I cannot do much about them. My current logic of the loop is to start with list(), and append the dataframe one by one. At the end:

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(...), listDataFrames)
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. If it is reasonable to do so, could you please also point out how to merge by the vector names in the above command? Thank you very much and Happy New Year.

Comment: Updated: I ended up adopting @Ronak Shah's suggesting, except I used do.call, not Reduce.  do.call kept my names for each vector as row names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `do.call` with `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^v")))

#   geneA geneB geneC geneD geneE
#v1     1    20     3     2    50
#v2    25    12    43     0    50
```

Instead of manually typing 50 vectors by hand we can find out if there exists a pattern in their naming convention. Based on the provided data it seems vector have names `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and so on. So using `ls` command we get all such objects which start with `v`. It will return a list of such objects.

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^v"))
#$v1
#geneA geneB geneC geneD geneE 
#    1    20     3     2    50 

#$v2
#geneA geneB geneC geneD geneE 
#   25    12    43     0    50
```

and now we `rbind` all such objects together. Since , the vectors follow the same order of names it should not be a problem.

---

Using the same logic with `Reduce` would also work

```
Reduce(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^v")))
```

Comment: Dear @Ronak - thank you very much! Your methods look great. One question though, the vectors will be generated inside of a loop, so they will thus have a same name... Are you suggesting that I assign different names to them?

Comment: @Helene yes, since if they have the same name then the vectors would be overwritten and you will loose them. If you are generating vectors in a loop you can also store them in a list instead and append them one by one. So in the answer you replace the `mget(ls......` part with the name of your list.